# Android Altbeacon .Print all found beacons informations using custom adapter and Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, altbeacon

I want to display UUID and Minor code of found beacons using listview in android.

I think I have problem with custom adapter.

Here is my actual code:

FoundBeacons.java

```
public class FoundBeacon extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {

private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private ListView listview;
private ArrayList<Beacon> beaconList;
private AdapterBeacon bAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_found_beacon);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.bind(this);

    beaconList = new ArrayList<Beacon>();
    this.bAdapter = new AdapterBeacon(this, beaconList);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(bAdapter);
}


@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        bAdapter.copyBeacons(beacons);
                        listview.setAdapter(bAdapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}
}
```

AdapterBeacon.java

```
public class AdapterBeacon extends ArrayAdapter<Beacon> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Beacon> allBeacons;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private boolean mNotifyOnChange = true;

public AdapterBeacon(Context context, ArrayList<Beacon> mBeacons) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_beacon);
    this.context = context;
    this.allBeacons = new ArrayList<Beacon>(mBeacons);
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return allBeacons .size();
}

@Override
public Beacon getItem(int position) {
    return allBeacons .get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Beacon item) {
    return allBeacons .indexOf(item);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1; //Number of types + 1 !!!!!!!!
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 1;
}


public void copyBeacons(Collection<Beacon> beacons)
{
    allBeacons.clear();
    for (Beacon b : beacons)
    {
        allBeacons.add(b);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_beacon,parent, false);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
                holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText(allBeacons.get(position).getId1().toString());
    holder.description.setText(allBeacons.get(position).getId2().toString());
    holder.pos = position;
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mNotifyOnChange = true;
}

public void setNotifyOnChange(boolean notifyOnChange) {
    mNotifyOnChange = notifyOnChange;
}


//---------------static views for each row-----------//
static class ViewHolder {

    TextView name;
    TextView description;
    int pos; //to store the position of the item within the list
}
}
```

activity_found_beacon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_found_beacon"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.pio.pd_inz_ibeacon.FoundBeacon">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/listview" />
```

row_beacon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"/>
```

Comment: What problems are you running into? Do you have any error messages? What is happening vs what you are expecting?

Comment: The list is empty. I want to print UUID and Major of beacons in range. I have 2 beacons that works (tested on another app).

Comment: I would set breakpoints / debug lines in each method in AdapterBeacon and see if there is any method that is not getting called.